# Create a sort column in SQL for hierarchy order based on NextId

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy table in SQL containing NodeId, ParentId, ChildId, NextId, NodeLevel, and a validity period (DateFrom, DateTo) since the location of a node within the hierarchy can change based on the date.  I am able to loop through the records recursively using the NodeId and ParentId with no problem.  The piece that I am missing is how to order the nodes.  The order of the nodes is based on ChildId, NextId, and validity period.  I need a way to dynamically add a sort column based on the validity period. This should give me a column called SortOrder that just numbers the nodes sequentially as they would appear if the hierarchy was displayed expanded down to the lowest level. The code to recreate the table I am using is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NextIDTest](
    [NodeName] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [NodeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChildId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NextId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NodeLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateFrom] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DateTo] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT [dbo].[NextIDTest] ([NodeName], [NodeId], [ParentId], [ChildId], [NextId], [NodeLevel], [DateFrom], [DateTo]) 
VALUES 
(N'TOTAL CAPITAL EXPENDITURE', 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'UTILITY CAPITAL EXPENDITURES', 2, 1, 3, 28, 2, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 1', 3, 2, 4, 24, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'NEW MAINS', 4, 3, 7, 9, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000713', 5, 4, 0, 8, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000712', 6, 4, 0, 5, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000711', 7, 4, 0, 6, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00007199', 8, 4, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'NEW SERVICES', 9, 3, 13, 14, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00007299', 10, 9, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000723', 11, 9, 0, 10, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000722', 12, 9, 0, 11, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000721', 13, 9, 0, 12, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000777', 14, 3, 0, 17, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000740', 15, 3, 0, 16, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2014-11-30' AS Date))
,(N'00000586', 16, 3, 0, 18, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000015', 17, 3, 0, 15, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'METERS', 18, 3, 20, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000023', 19, 18, 0, 21, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000021', 20, 18, 0, 19, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'IND AND COMM SOLUTIONS', 21, 18, 23, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000024', 22, 21, 0, 0, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000022', 23, 21, 0, 22, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 2', 24, 2, 25, 29, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'BARE STEEL', 25, 24, 27, 40, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000319', 26, 25, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000119', 27, 25, 0, 26, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'NON-UTILITY CAPITAL EXPENDITURES', 28, 1, 35, 0, 2, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 3', 29, 2, 52, 30, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 4', 30, 2, 55, 31, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 5', 31, 2, 57, 32, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 6', 32, 2, 125, 129, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'NON-UTILITY', 33, 28, 122, 0, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT', 34, 28, 120, 33, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'GAS STORAGE', 35, 28, 95, 34, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000320', 37, 24, 0, 39, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000120', 38, 24, 0, 37, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000112', 39, 24, 0, 127, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'LEAKAGE', 40, 24, 59, 128, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'GENERAL', 41, 29, 79, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'GAS SUPPLY', 42, 29, 71, 41, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'REGULATORS', 43, 29, 66, 42, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000336', 44, 29, 0, 46, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000318', 45, 29, 0, 43, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000317', 46, 29, 0, 45, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000140', 47, 29, 0, 50, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000136', 48, 29, 0, 44, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000115', 49, 29, 0, 47, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000014', 50, 29, 0, 48, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'RELOCATES/ABANDONMENTS', 51, 29, 64, 126, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'PUBLIC WORKS', 52, 29, 62, 51, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000585', 53, 30, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'LAND AND STRUCTURES', 54, 30, 86, 53, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY', 55, 30, 83, 54, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'TOTAL NON-UTIL INTERSTATE STOR', 56, 31, 93, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'TOTAL UTILITY STORAGE PROJECTS', 57, 31, 87, 56, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000313', 58, 40, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000113', 59, 40, 0, 58, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000314', 60, 52, 0, 61, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000117', 61, 52, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000114', 62, 52, 0, 60, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000316', 63, 51, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000116', 64, 51, 0, 63, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000019', 65, 43, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000013', 66, 43, 0, 65, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000529', 67, 42, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000524', 68, 42, 0, 67, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000018', 69, 42, 0, 68, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000012', 70, 42, 0, 69, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000011', 71, 42, 0, 70, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000571', 72, 41, 0, 73, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000509', 73, 41, 0, 74, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000044', 74, 41, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000043', 75, 41, 0, 76, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000040', 76, 41, 0, 80, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000035', 77, 41, 0, 78, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000033', 78, 41, 0, 75, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000032', 79, 41, 0, 77, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000031', 80, 41, 0, 72, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000039', 81, 55, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000038', 82, 55, 0, 81, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000017', 83, 55, 0, 82, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000511', 84, 54, 0, 85, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000036', 85, 54, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000034', 86, 54, 0, 84, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000569', 87, 57, 0, 88, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000562', 88, 57, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000581', 89, 56, 0, 90, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000563', 90, 56, 0, 124, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2014-11-30' AS Date))
,(N'00000514', 91, 56, 0, 92, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000513', 92, 56, 0, 89, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000512', 93, 56, 0, 91, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'GAS STORAGE LLC', 94, 35, 116, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'OTHER STORAGE', 95, 35, 96, 94, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'OTHER (COMPANY 1234)', 96, 95, 111, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000480', 97, 96, 0, 112, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000470', 98, 96, 0, 97, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000460', 99, 96, 0, 98, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000450', 100, 96, 0, 99, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000440', 101, 96, 0, 100, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000430', 102, 96, 0, 101, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000420', 104, 96, 0, 102, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000410', 111, 96, 0, 104, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000401', 112, 96, 0, 0, 6, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000491', 113, 94, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000489', 114, 94, 0, 117, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000486', 115, 94, 0, 113, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000481', 116, 94, 0, 114, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000413', 117, 94, 0, 115, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000508', 118, 34, 0, 119, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000507', 119, 34, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000506', 120, 34, 0, 121, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000505', 121, 34, 0, 118, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000587', 122, 33, 0, 123, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000510', 123, 33, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000564', 124, 56, 0, 0, 5, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2014-11-30' AS Date))
,(N'00000760', 125, 32, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000752', 126, 29, 0, 49, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000751', 127, 24, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000750', 128, 24, 0, 38, 4, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'CATEGORY 7', 129, 2, 132, 0, 3, CAST(N'1000-01-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000740', 130, 129, 0, 0, 4, CAST(N'2014-12-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000564', 131, 129, 0, 130, 4, CAST(N'2014-12-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
,(N'00000563', 132, 129, 0, 131, 4, CAST(N'2014-12-01' AS Date), CAST(N'9999-12-31' AS Date))
GO
```

EDIT:

Expected output would look like this:

```
NodeName                                                     NodeId      ParentId    ChildId     NextId      NodeLevel   SortOrder
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
TOTAL CAPITAL EXPENDITURE                                    1           0           2           0           1           1
UTILITY CAPITAL EXPENDITURES                                 2           1           3           28          2           2
CATEGORY 1                                                   3           2           4           24          3           3
NEW MAINS                                                    4           3           7           9           4           4
00000713                                                     5           4           0           8           5           7
00000712                                                     6           4           0           5           5           6
00000711                                                     7           4           0           6           5           5
00007199                                                     8           4           0           0           5           8
```

Comment: What does "based on the validity period" mean, if it doesn't simply mean ordering by a certain column?

Comment: please provide the expected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I really got this correctly, but this might be what you are looking for:

Btw: You do not need all these columns in your table (ChildId, NextId and NodeLevel will result out of the query). It is quite erronous actually to keep them as stored values...

Btw: Next time please try to reduce your example to a small amount of rows and add the expected output fitting to the given data. This makes it much easier to understand what you really need...

```
--A recursive CTE traverses down the hierarchy
WITH RecCTE AS
(
    SELECT NodeName,NodeId,ParentId,1 AS NodeLevel,DateFrom,DateTo 
    FROM NextIDTest
    WHERE ParentId=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.NodeName,y.NodeId,y.ParentId,x.NodeLevel+1,y.DateFrom,y.DateTo
    FROM RecCTE AS x
    INNER JOIN NextIDTest AS y ON x.NodeId=y.ParentId
)
--the second CTE will take the ResultSet as it comes out of recCTE and number it
,Numbered AS --
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RunningNumber,*
    FROM RecCTE
)
--the third CTE will get another numbering, don't know if this really is what you need
,InternalSort AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NodeLevel ORDER BY DateFrom DESC,RunningNumber) AS InternalSort,*
    FROM Numbered
)
--And finally this is again numbered "as is"
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS YourSortColumn,*
FROM InternalSort
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I apologize for being verbose and unclear.  You are correct that I do not really need all of those columns.  In fact, looking at it again, I realize that I do not need to consider the date range when sorting the columns.  I do need to be able to use ChildId and NextId in order to determine the sort order.   The expected output would look like this:

Comment: @DerrickVanHoeter, did you try my query? Just use your own test scenario and put my query behind (you need a `;` as separation). Isn't this quite close to what you need?

Comment: Shnugo.  Yes.  I tried your query.  It does not use NextId at all so it is correct some of the time but not all of the time.  I really appreciate your assistance especially considering that I did not provide very good information to begin with.

Comment: @DerrickVanHoeter If I didn't get this wrong, the `NextId` is not needed to build the hierarchy. This is fully derived out of id and parentid. Might be it's enough to include your `NextId` into the `ORDER BY` of the "InternalSort" (to enforce an level-internal rank)

Comment: The NextId column is not sortable numerically since the NextId could be anywhere in the hierarchy.  Looking through the code again, the logic would have to go like this: Start with the node where ParentId=0 and assign it SortOrder=1. Go to the ChildId for the next record. If ChildId=0, use NextId. If both NextId and ChildId are 0, go to the NextId of the ParentId.

Comment: @DerrickVanHoeter to be honest, I doubt, that this structure is the best for this... Try the following: Take just the first CTE "RecCTE" and write below the paranthesis `SELECT * FROM RecCTE`. Now try around until you get the hierarchy you want...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110405/discussion-between-derrick-van-hoeter-and-shnugo).